# NPM - Sub-dependencies are in another location after upgraded to Node v.5.0.0 - Why?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a problem with `npm install {moduleName}`

previously, all my sub-dependencies were installed under `{projectName}/node_modules/{moduleName}/node_modules/`

After I upgraded to Node v5.0.0 (via installer on website), all my sub-dependencies are installed together with the dependencies under `{projectName}/node_modules/`

Why is that happening? And how can I change it back to the previous behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node v5.x comes with npm 3.x. This is the intended behavior in npm 3.x. You can read more about it in the [npm 3.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0), but here's the gist:

> Your dependencies will now be installed *maximally flat*. Insofar as is possible, all of your dependencies, and their dependencies, and THEIR dependencies will be installed in your project's `node_modules` folder with no nesting. You'll only see modules nested underneath one another when two (or more) modules have conflicting dependencies.

I'm not sure why you'd want the old behavior—it was a dependency nightmare, hence the change—but if you really want to you can downgrade to npm 2.x:

```
$ npm install -g npm@latest-2
```